# pdsh command failed with connection refused

Tags: ssh, sles

I'm able to remote login the target host with ssh. But when I execute a command through `pdsh`, it fails with `connection refused`. Both systems are sles11.

I found a description of the error on [this](http://www.kumanov.com/docstore/manuals/hp-ux/en/T2786-90291/ch04s04.html) page as follows.

**Message**:
pdsh@local_hostname: target_hostname:connect: Connection refused

**Cause**:
The target system is unreachable, or the r services may be disabled for this system.

**To Correct**:
Check the r services and whether the target system is up and connected.

In my case, the target system is up so the cause should be the disabled r services.
So what are `r services` and how could I enable it?

Comment: The "r services" are rsh and its friends, who live in `/etc/inetd.conf`. But I'd advice you to first read the documentation for pdsh to figure out if you can make it connect through ssh; rsh and its friends have pretty much no concept of security.

Comment: I can't find that `/etc/inetd.conf`. Is rsh a service?

Comment: How about doing a web search for "r services unix" or "rsh"? You'll find loads of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pdsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdsh) uses [rsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_shell) by default, not [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). Rsh, rlogin and rcmd are the “r services”; they are deprecated and your system rightly doesn't have them available. Ssh is the modern alternative to the r services; it is preferred because it encrypts and authenticates connections (and also because it's more flexible than the old, quirky r commands). Tell pdsh to use ssh:

```
pdsh -R ssh …
```

or set the `PDSH_RCMD_TYPE` environment variable to `ssh`:

```
export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh
pdsh …
```

Comment: indeed, thanks. Also, ssh module is not installed by default so I have to `./configure --with-ssh`